# Returning one value from function in Python and plotting it on a heatmap

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I have used the following code to produce a heatmap for a given function. Here it is calculating the global lyapunov exponent for a variation of the logistic map - I've added the parameter of p. Where this is fine, I don't actually care about what the exact value of the global lyapunov exponent is, but rather if it is positive or negative.

Here is the code I've been using:

```
# Logistic Function
def p_logistic(A, x, p):
    return (A/4) * (((p+1)**(p+1))/(p**p)) * (x**p) * (1-x)

# Lyapunov Exponent
def p_lyap(A, x, p):
    return np.log(abs((A/4) * (((p+1)**(p+1))/(p**p)) * (p*(x**(p-1)) - (p+1)*(x**p))))

n = 500
A = np.linspace(2, 4, n)
p = np.linspace(0.5, 5, n)

def F(A, p):
    A, p = np.meshgrid(A, p)
    lyapunov = 0
    x = 0.9
    N = 100

    for i in range(0,N):
        lyapunov = lyapunov + p_lyap(A, x, p)
        x = p_logistic(A, x, p)

    global_lyapunov = lyapunov/N
    return global_lyapunov

z = F(A, p)
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
xlabels = ['{:3.1f}'.format(x) for x in A]
ylabels = ['{:3.1f}'.format(y) for y in p]
ax = sns.heatmap(z, xticklabels = A, yticklabels = p)
```

I have tried using if statements to return the global lyapunov exponent as 1 if it is greater than 0, and -1 if it is less than 0, but it returned the error

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Essentially I would like only 3 colours in my heat map, one for when the global lyapunov exponent is negative, equal to 0 and positive. is there any way this is possible?

Comment: You should add the code that generated the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming I'm interpreting you correctly, I'd just do something like:

```
zd = np.zeros_like(z, dtype=int)
zd[z > 0] = 1
zd[z < 0] = -1
```

and then plot `zd` instead of `z`

also note, you might be better off using `imshow` from directly from `matplotlib` that way you can get nicer axis labels, e.g:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.imshow(zd, extent=(2, 4, 5, 0.5), aspect='auto')
plt.colorbar()
```

`imshow` doesn't doesn't do any rescaling of values that `heatmap` does, which is probably better for your use case

also there seem to be a lot of values that aren't defined, so it might be worth treating them specially, e.g:

```
zd[~np.isfinite(z)] = 0
```

giving a final plot of:

[image: implot]

but I'm not sure if I got the axes the right way around

Comment: This worked perfectly! I flipped the y axis just as the graph produced upside down but other than that it's great. Thank you!

Comment: yup, wasn't sure which way around the coordinates went.  I've just found this link:  https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/imshow_extent.html which looks useful!

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.sign` is an easy way to get the data you want. Also, seems you intended to use `xlabel` and `ylabel`:

```
sns.heatmap(np.sign(z), xticklabels=xlabel, yticklabels=ylabel)
```